# How to organize adonisjs project using open source component

Tags: git, npm, open-source, adonis.js

I have a side project using AdonisJS. It has its own private repository.

I have a few javascript modules being used by the project but that I would like to keep separate, so I can for example put them as open source projects in GitHub, have their own tests and documentation. They are basically math algorithms.

Right now, what I'm doing is copying the files to the repo when I make changes. But I don't like that.
I could make npm packages of them, and just fetch them. But then when I modify them, I would have to push, update the package, and then update the version in the adonis project. Not nice.

What is the best practice for such cases?

I was thinking of git submodules, and adding a step somehow that node copies the files to the correct folder on certain instruction, but I'm not sure that's the best way.